# JTable based on a list of Objects, like TableView's items list

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have an application that was using a JavaFX TableView, but I need to switch to using a JTable because of certain issues I was running into.

TableViews take in a list of objects and each column is a field in each object, for example, a Person object with columns for First Name, Last Name, and email. If you edited the email field in the table, it would go out and edit the email in that Person object. If I selected rows in the table, I could get the Person objects from those selected indices.

Is there a way to do this in JTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom `TableModel` for your `Person` object.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) which gives a step by step example how you might do this.

It also provide a generic class to make the implementation easier and include additional generic methods for accessing the data in the TableModel.

You can also follow the `BeanTableModel` link for a `TableModel` you can use without any custom code.

Comment: thanks! I will check that out, it seems to be what I need